# directive communication and coupling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives, dropdown and panel.

Panels contain dropdowns. Using require : "^panel", and specifying a controller, I can make both communicate.

You can see an example here

http://plnkr.co/edit/rqBsZ26JiQKzFMRpBmKD?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-rc2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular
      .module("app", [])
      .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.test = "Welcome"
      })
      .directive("dropdown", function() {
        return {
          require: "^panel",
          constraint: "E",
          transclude: true,
          scope: {},
          template: "<div>{{selectedValue}}<select ng-model='selectedValue'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></div>",
          link: function(scope, b, c, panelController) {
            scope.selectedValue = 1;

            scope.$watch('selectedValue', function(newVal, oldVal) {
              panelController.setValue2(newVal)
            })
          }
        }
      })
      .directive("panel", function() {
        return {
          constraint: "E",
          transclude: true,
          controller: function($scope) {
            this.setValue2 = function(val) {
              $scope.value2 = val;

              if (val == 1) {
                $scope.style1 = true;
                $scope.style2 = false;
              }

              if (val == 2) {
                $scope.style1 = !true;
                $scope.style2 = !false;
              }
            }
          },
          template: "<div ng-class='{panel: true, style1: style1, style2: style2}'><h2>Value: {{value2}}</h2><br><dropdown></dropdown></div>",
          scope: {},
          link: function(scope, b, c) {}
        }
      })
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>{{test}}</h1>
  <panel></panel>
  <panel></panel>
  <panel></panel>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is about how to make the dropdown directive independent too, so I want this two:

1) The dropdown directive to work by itself, so I can put  in my html and
2) Sometimes, inside other directives like panel

I was thinking that I could generate the returned directive object and, if needed, add to that object the controller mention when needed.

Is that the right way to remove the tight coupling that now I have between panel and dropdown while allowing me still the flexibility to use dropdown in any other scenario?

Please find the updated plunkr containing the rahil recommendations, fully working

http://plnkr.co/edit/rqBsZ26JiQKzFMRpBmKD?p=preview

Comment: I don't know but the `dropdown` directive working independently too.

Comment: thanks rahil, if you look at the console you will see it is throwing an error

Comment: Thats because `panel` is no longer parent directive and the fourth parameter of `dropdown` directive controller is `undefined`, you can simply avoid that by using `if` condition and place `?` to your `require` property `require : "?^panel"` so parent controller will be optional.

Comment: great! that fixed the problem, where did you find info about that ?, I have been reading a lot about angular but it is the first time I see this one, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-